# Why is the fade-in not working with this CSS?

Tags: html, css, transition

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="x.php">X</a></li>
      <li><a href="y.php">Y</a></li>
      <li><a href="z.php">Z</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    width:170px;
    margin:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition:visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

I want the first level to fade in, on hover on a list item of the main menu, but it just doesn't seem to work. I have spent hours on it and I'm not sure what's really wrong. Any pointers?

If you need to see the complete code: http://paperbird.in/projects/BusinessConclave/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Ok, you contributed your website, so here's the solution, actually the `transition` does work, but `z-index` is causing you an issue there, so it flicks the sub menu instantly.. though it transits, use `z-index: 100;` for `.nav ul li:hover > ul` on line **153** in *style.css* and make sure you remove `visibility` properties as they are not required.

---

First of all, your markup is invalid, you cannot nest `ul` as a direct descendant to `ul` so nest that in an `li` and secondly, you cannot transit `visibility` property, so only use `opacity` and get rid of the `visibility` property as well. If you want, you can also use `animation-timing-function` property with a value of `linear` for a consistent *fadein* and *fadeout* effect.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FEW49/)

```
.nav ul ul{
     position:absolute;  
     opacity:0; 
     width:170px;  
     margin:0;
     -webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
     -moz-transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
     transition:opacity 0.3s linear; 
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul{ 
    opacity:1;
}
```

And make sure you declare properietary properties before general properties.

Comment: @Juhana I was talking about `<ul class="nav"> <ul>`

Comment: The visibility is required. Try hovering your cursor over the little portion underneath "About" in the menu, and see that the drop down fades in, while it should not.

Here's the tutorial I referred to: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: @Smartflight Ok than, you can keep it if it's not harming you :)

Comment: Yeah. It is required in my case. Thanks for the help. I feel stupid now. Haha.

Comment: @Smartflight nothing to feel stupid, everyone starts and gets stuck at some point :) and you welcome...